# How to test a click on a button or link icon in testRigor?

Tags: testrigor

In my website, I have to click in an icon to be able to edit a user settings. So I want to be able to create a test in testRigor to click in this icon and edit the user settings. For example, if I want to create a test to click in a button that it's written "Edit", I just have to write in the test steps: press "Edit", but if instead of written "Edit", it's just an icon/image what should I write, press "???" ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my description, let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Hey, please do post code(if any) you have worked till now.

Answer (score 0):

In [testRigor](https://testrigor.com?rf=so) you have multiple ways to refer to elements on the screen. Of course, there is a visible text you can rely on it. However, there are many more like:

```
click "Edit"
```

in case you enabled ML-based image classification and the icon looks like an edit icon. You can see all supported icons [here](https://testrigor.com/docs/image-classes/).
Or the button has aria-label set to "Edit".
Or one of CSS classes contains "edit".

Alternatively, you can rely on relative locations and indexes. For example:

```
click on the second button on the right of "Something"
click on the third button on the right of stored value "myId"
```

In general, all of the ways to refer to elements are described [here](https://testrigor.com/docs/language/#referencing).